# Word for a person who wakes up?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

**I was thinking about if there is a word like "waker" and what meanings it has, or how would people feel about it if they heard it.**

Can we call the person who wakes others up a waker?

And if I call a person an early waker or an every day waker, can it also mean that he is a person who wakes up (himself) early/every day? Like if he is using some alarm clock app every day for waking up, can we call him a daily waker?

Do you think the word has both meanings, the word does not exist or the word has only the first meaning?

Thanks :)

Comment: We call someone who wakes early an "early riser" . Waking someone else: "I roused him".

Comment: How would people feel about it if they heard **waker**? It sits uneasily, with **daily waker** and **every day waker** awkward. The question should have been asked on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary? What did it tell you? A few good ones online include [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/), [Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/), [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/), [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/), and [MacMillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb **wake** is both transitive and intransitive. In the same way, the agent noun **waker** can mean:

> 1. **waker** - someone who rouses others from sleep.
> 2. **waker** - a person who awakes; "an early waker"
>
> ([thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/waker))

Comment: As Reg Dwight has said, '[W]e write stuff in comments that is too obvious to qualify for an answer. [This (the mere looking up of a word)] is not really a suitable answer on a site for linguists and etymologists....'

Comment: This is a legitimate answer and it is actually very appropriate.

Comment: @fraulau _When_ did LMGTFY responses become acceptable answers? ELU is aimed at linguists and etymologists. ELL is for more basic questions, and they'd have probably not wanted a question lacking such basic research there either.

Answer (score 0):

These answers are right. But, as with everything written, it depends on the context.

Simply put, wake is a verb - for now. It's not a noun in the way you want to use it. There's no such thing as a waker (as in a person), unless you found it in some royal court or something. Seriously, someone probably did have to wake up His/Her Highness. That person probably had a title. Hmmm, Lord of the Awakening?We have examples of that now. The verb marry has noun forms that are titles: priest, justice of the peace, rabbi, etc. However, there is no "marrier". It's not hard to make the conversion from wake to waker. Most English verbs have a noun counterpart. Think jog/jogger, sleep/sleeper, and kill/killer.

You can look up the accepted noun use. It's a dead person's remembrance party before burial and the turbulence caused by ships and airplanes as they traverse their routes.

However, don't count "waker" out just yet. A quick look at the OED shows that "misconstructor" was added in 2002.

Back to context... if you're writing a poem or a song then you have poetic license. Again, a quick search for "poem containing the word 'Waker'" brings up Sir Thomas Wyatt using it. There's also some song on YouTube that uses it as its title to refer to a person.

Bottom line though, I wouldn't try using it in Scrabble.

> > Forgot to ask, are you in the U.K.? "Waker", spoken, is dangerously close to "wanker" - British slang for jerkin' off.

Comment: Wordnet licenses the 'someone who rouses others from sleep' usage. As mahmud koya had already mentioned.

Comment: Scrabble is about the ***only*** place I’d use it.